# Error when writing --datadir in terminal

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, genesis

I'm trying to follow this tutorial :

https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_messaging%3B0b%2F8A0z8RdyP%20D3E%2F%20bJLA%3D%3D

I am not exactly sure if I am following the steps correct but I get an error when I write the command in the terminal `CustomGenesis.json --datadir`

The error is:

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

Does anyone can help me solve this error and explain me what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one single command, not 3

```
$ geth --datadir /your/datadir --identity yourIdentity init /your/genesis/file
```

also `init` is a command and not an option (therefore `init` instead of `--init`)

please have a look here

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options